# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') when upgrade to webpack 3

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am developing a google chrome extension, today I tried to upgrade the webpack to verison 3(the legacy was webpack 1.x). Now I am almost complete and the compile works fine, but when I open the google chrome extension popup page, it could not show the UI element. Then I open the popup debbbugger console and shows error log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9e5832947e0eb0ffd7bf:54:1)
    at Object.500 (popup.js:115:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 9e5832947e0eb0ffd7bf:54:1)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 9e5832947e0eb0ffd7bf:25:1)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 9e5832947e0eb0ffd7bf:19:1)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (commons1.js:20:36)
    at popup.js:1:1
```

I check the bootstrap `"bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",` version and it was the newest version which last update was 3 years ago. why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? this is my project `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "xpostinstall": "node ./build/install-pdf-viewer",
    "dev": "webpack --config build/webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build": "gulp --cwd . --gulpfile build/gulp-build.js",
    "test": "karma start build/karma.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "chrome-call": "^1.0.2",
    "connect.io": "^3.1.3",
    "interact.js": "^1.2.6",
    "translation.js": "github:jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js",
    "vue": "^1.0.24",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.5.0",
    "chrome-env": "^0.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "download": "^5.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-jsonmin": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.2.0",
    "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-coveralls": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.6",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.22.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "license": "GPLv3",
}
```

and this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require( 'webpack' ) ,
  CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin ,
  ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' );

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    bg : './src/background-scripts/' ,
    content : ['./src/content-scripts/firefox-fix.js', './src/content-scripts/'] ,
    options : './src/options/' ,
    popup : './src/popup/' ,
    'bs-lite' : './src/public/bootstrap-lite.scss'
  } ,
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/bundle') ,
    filename : '[name].js'
  } ,
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.js$/ ,
        exclude : [ /node_modules(?!(\/|\\?\\)(translation\.js|selection-widget|connect\.io|chrome-env)\1)/ ] ,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      } ,
      {
        test : /\.woff$/ ,
        loader : 'file-loader' ,
        query : {
          name : '[name].[ext]'
        }
      } ,
      {
        test : /\.html$/ ,
        loader : 'vue-html-loader'
      } , 
      {
        test : /\.(css|scss)$/ ,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback :'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                implementation: require('sass')
              }
            }]
        })
      }
    ]
  } ,
  plugins : [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin( {
      name : 'commons1',
      filename : 'commons1.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'content' , 'popup' ] 
    }) ,
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ 
      name: 'commons2',
      filename :'commons2.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'commons1.js' , 'options' ] 
    }) ,
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ 
      name: 'commons3',
      filename :'commons3.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'bg' , 'commons2.js' ] 
    }) ,
    new ExtractTextPlugin( '[name].css' )
  ]
};
```

I have no idea about how to fix this problem, anyone facing the same problem? I have tried to add   `allChunks: true` in the CommonsChunkPlugin but did not works. I also tried to move the popup chunk in front of others to control the order like this:

```
new CommonsChunkPlugin( {
      name : 'commons1',
      filename : 'commons1.js' , 
      allChunks: true,
      chunks : [ 'popup','content' ],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual',
    }) ,
```

still did not work. Any one facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite simple. Probably you are using multiple apps builded via weback on same page.
**Solution:** [Change output.jsonpFunction](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputjsonpfunction)